# How many times variable m is updated

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, discrete-mathematics

Given the following pseudo-code, the question is how many times on average is the variable **m** being updated.

```
A[1...n]: array with n random elements 
m = a[1]
for I = 2 to n do
   if a[I] < m then m = a[I]
end for
```

One might answer that since all elements are random, then the variable will be updated on average on half the number of iterations of the for loop plus one for the initialization.

However, I suspect that there must be a better (and possibly the only correct) way to prove it using binomial distribution with **p = 1/2**. This way, the average number of updates on **m** would be

`M = 1 + Σi=1 to n-1[k.Cn,k.pk.(1-p)(n-k)]`

where **C<sub>n,k</sub>** is the binomial coefficient. I have tried to solve this but I have stuck some steps after since I do not know how to continue.

Could someone explain me which of the two answers is correct and if it is the second one, show me how to calculate **M**?

Thank you for your time

Comment: It certainly depends on the type and range of A[i].
For instance, if A[i] are from {0,1}, then it can be updated max. 1 time.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the elements of the array are distinct, the expected number of updates of `m` is the n<sup>th</sup> [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), H<sub>n</sub>, which is the sum of 1/k for k ranging from 1 to n.

The summation formula can also be represented by the recursion:

```
H1 = 1
Hn = Hn−1+1/n (n > 1)
```

It's easy to see that the recursion corresponds to the problem.

Consider all permutations of n−1 numbers, and assume that the expected number of assignments is H<sub>n−1</sub>. Now, every permutation of n numbers consists of a permutation of n−1 numbers, with a new smallest number inserted in one of n possible insertion points: either at the beginning, or after one of the n−1 existing values. Since it is smaller than every number in the existing series, it will only be assigned to m in the case that it was inserted at the beginning. That has a probability of 1/n, and so the expected number of assignments of a permutation of n numbers is H<sub>n−1</sub> + 1/n.

Since the expected number of assignments for a vector of length one is obviously 1, which is H<sub>1</sub>, we have an inductive proof of the recursion.

H<sub>n</sub> is asymptotically equal to ln n + γ where γ is [the Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), approximately 0.577. So it increases without limit, but quite slowly.

The values for which `m` is updated are called *left-to-right maxima*, and you'll probably find more information about them by searching for that term.

Comment: @rici Wouldn’t the same logic apply if we allow for equal elements?

Comment: @algrid: it depends on the range of possible values, as Palo points out in a comment to the question. If the range is large enough, the result is asymptotically equal, but for small ranges, the expected number of local minima is smaller. Insisting on distinct elements simplifies the computation.

Comment: @rici Ah, yes, I see, with duplicates we can’t rely on Hn-1 and the induction won’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I liked [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52134199/4081336) answer so I decided to elaborate its central argument a little bit more so to make it clearer to me.

Let `H[k]` be the expected number of assignments needed to compute the min `m` of an array of length `k`, as indicated in the algorithm under consideration. We know that

```
H[1] = 1.
```

Now assume we have an array of length `n > 1`. The min can be in the last position of the array or not. It is in the last position with probability `1/n`. It is not with probability `1 - 1/n`. In the first case the expected number of assignments is `H[n-1] + 1`. In the second, `H[n-1]`.

If we multiply the expected number of assignments of each case by their probabilities and sum, we get

```
H[n] = (H[n-1] + 1)*1/n + H[n-1]*(1 - 1/n)
     = H[n-1]*1/n + 1/n + H[n-1] - H[n-1]*1/n
     = 1/n + H[n-1]
```

which shows the recursion.

Note that the argument is valid if the min is either in the last position or in any the first `n-1`, not in both places. Thus we are using that all the elements of the array are different.